# c++ Initializer list

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a question about c++ Initializer list, I see the following code somewhere:

```
class A {
public:
  A(String sender, String receiver, String service) {
                                                        //do something here
                                                    }
}

class B {
public:
  B(String sender, String receiver, String service) {
                                                        //do something here
                                                    }
}
```

Then the object is created in the following way:

```
A::A(sender,receiver, service) : B(sender,receiver, service) {
//do something here
}
```

does B will also be created based on the paramaters passed?
How could this happen?

Comment: Something is wrong. Did you mean `class B : public A {` instead of `class B {`? (Or vice versa with the classes in the other order? Or something like that.)

Comment: btw. what you mean is (c++ grammar) the _ctor-initializer_, or _mem-initializer-list_. Calling it "initializer list" might lead to confusion with _initializer-list_ which is "the stuff in `{}` to initialize aggregates (and more in C++11)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you posted is wrong.

First, to call `B`'s constructor like that, `A` has to be derived from `B`.

Second, you provide 2 implementations for `A::A`.

I'll explain on the following example:

```
class B
{
   int _x;
public:
   B();
   B(int x);
}

B::B()
{
   _x = 42;
}
B::B(int x)
{
   _x = x;
}

class A : public B
{
public:
    A(int x);
};

A::A(int x) : B(x) {}
```

Now, since `A` is-a `B` (that's what inheritance is), whenever you construct an `A`, a base object - `B`- will also be constructed. If you don't specify it in the initializer list, the default constructor for `B` - `B::B()` will be called. Even though you don't declare on, it does exist.

If you specify a different version of the constructor - like in this case, `B::B(int)`, that version will be called.

It's just the way the language is designed.

EDIT:

I edited the code a bit.

Assume the following definition of `A`'s constructor:

```
A::A(int x) : B(x) {}
//...
A a(10);
//a._x will be 10
```

If however your constructor is defined as:

```
A::A(int x) {}
```

`B`'s default constructor will be called:

```
A a(10);
//a._x will be 42
```

Hope that's clear.